# UsagePlanKeys cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an API key and want to associate it with my usage plan via cloudformation using the following template, but it isn't working:

```
"usagePlanKey":
    {
    "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlanKey",
    "Properties":{
    "UsagePlanId":{"Ref":"usagePlan"},
    "KeyId":{"Ref":"ApiKey"},
    "KeyType":"API_KEY"
    }
```

Can I create a resource if it's not yet realized by AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create Types that have not been implemented in CloudFormation, the current list of Resources support for the CloudFormation ApiGateway service are:

- AWS::ApiGateway::Account
- AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey
- AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
- AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
- AWS::ApiGateway::ClientCertificate
- AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
- AWS::ApiGateway::Method
- AWS::ApiGateway::Model
- AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
- AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
- AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
- AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html

There is a similar question here;

[Can you create Usage Plan with Cloud Formation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910734/can-you-create-usage-plan-with-cloud-formation/39919130#39919130)

It seems that the current solution involves having to manually add API Keys to a usage plan

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation currently does not let you create an association between the ApiKey and UsagePlan, see this: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2539#issuecomment-264809452